# Is the derivative the unique operation on points in the plane that preserves convexity?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, plane-geometry

Let $C(n)$ be the space of multisets of size $n$ of points in the Euclidean plane, topologised appropriately, and consider a surjective continuous map: $$D:C(n)\rightarrow C(n-1)$$

Such that the convex hull of $D(S)$ is contained in the convex hull of $S$, and if a multiset $S$ has $x$ occurring $k>0$ times, then $D(S)$ has $x$ occurring $k-1$ times.

If we identify the plane with $\mathbb{C}$, multisets with polynomials, then by the Gauss-Lucas theorem, the derivative is a map with this property, for $n\geq 2$.

Does this property characterise the derivative? So for $n\geq 2$, is this the only continuous map between these spaces with this property?

Comment: Well, you, probably, want to add some extra assumptions. Otherwise something as boring as, say, center of mass repeated $n-1$ times works...

Comment: Ahh thanks, I added another condition, really I want to know if the derivative is uniquely defined by its metric behaviour on zeros (multisets), but I'm not sure how to best phrase that precisely.

Comment: Let $f$ be an odd function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(-1,1)$ (e.g. $2\arctan(x)/\pi$).

Then for $n=2$ take $\{x,y\}\mapsto 
\{((1+f(\mathrm{Re}(x) - \mathrm{Re}(y)))x + (1-f(\mathrm{Re}(x) - \mathrm{Re}(y)))y)/2\}$.


For $f=0$ you get the derivative.

Comment: @GabrielC.Drummond-Cole This is an answer, is not it?

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე Formally yes, but really it is just another example showing that more conditions are required. I would suggest to combine surjectivity and  invariance under complex linear mappings. Then for $n=2$, the midpoint becomes the only option and that is the derivative. But I'm pessimistic about large $n$ even after that. The actual question here seems to be "Is there any list of natural (whatever that means) properties to require to get an affirmative answer?"

Comment: I will formulate this as an answer if @ChrisH thinks it is sufficient, but I tend to agree with fedja here.

Comment: without something like the multiplicity condition in the question, "surjectivity + invariance" as suggested by fedja looks like it's probably possible with a weighted average of derivative with center of mass (I didn't check surjectivity rigorously).

Comment: I'd prefer to leave the question up still I think, since it really is the general behaviour for all $n$ that I'm interested in. However, I would accept any answer which can characterise the derivative using these kind of geometric considerations (for instance partial unitary invariance, as submultisets of $S^2$).